# Python: apply future division to all files

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm using Python 2, and I need `from __future__ import division`, to make sure the division has proper value.

The problem is that, I have multiple files that all need this `import`.

[image]

This means I need to add this line to almost every file in this folder, it feels quite repetative. Is there anything I can do?

Comment: That's a good thing. Someone editing one of the files won't be surprised by the fact that `/` never performs integer division despite the fact that `from __future__ import division` doesn't appear in the file.

Comment: Agreed, further more, I don't believe that this behavior is possible without an import. So, it's better to keep it clear, or upgrade to Python 3.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you have a lot of files, you could just write a script to put that line in every file.  Something along these lines.

```
 import os
 for (dirpath, dirnames, filenames) in os.walk('.'):
   for file in filenames:
     if file.endswith('.py'):
       with open(file,'r') as f:
         txt = f.readlines()
       if not txt.startswith('from __future__ import division\n'):
         with open(file,'w') as g:
           g.write('from __future__ import division\n' + txt)
```

Comment: What about empty lines and comment lines at the beginning or the shebang line?

Comment: For searching, you could check if that line is in the file, and for finding the correct insertion point, you could search for other import statements and go directly before them.